# How do I restore the MySQL root user's privileges?

Tags: mysql, root

I accidentally removed most of the privileges from my MySQL root user, including the ability to grant privileges. Is there some way I can restore this user to its original state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might still be able to do an `UPDATE` on table `user` in database `mysql`:

```
USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET Grant_priv='1' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If step 3 doesn't work, restarting the MySQL server will have the same effect.  If step 2 doesn't work, you need to restore `mysql.user` from backup.  If you don't have a backup, make a backup, reinstall MySQL and then selectively restore your backup, leaving out tables within the `mysql` database.

**UPDATE**

You're getting Access Denied during the first step.  At this point, you're down to the alternative solutions with backups.  There's no way (that I know of or can easily imagine) that you're recovering those tables any other way.

**UPDATE 2**

The exact error message is basically saying that in addition to losing root's `grant` privileges, you've dropped root's access to the `mysql` DB.  Without having access to that DB and without having `grant` privileges, the only way I can see back is to somehow obtain a fresh copy of the `mysql` DB.

Any chance you have a replication slave set up?

Comment: Access denied during the first step.

Comment: In case the exact error message is in some way more useful: ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

Comment: Got this working by using temporarily --skip-grant-tables for mysqld. Once that was done granting privileges worked fine. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html has details for anyone else who might run into the same issue.