# lost mysql root user privelages

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

I using mariadb and my mysql root user lost all of privelages. so everything gives me the "access denied" now.

I tried to reinstall mysql but it's looks like the configure files not deleted.

how can I fix it when I can't access to mysql table and even can't have another fress install.

by the way I using ubuntu 16.04 and according to this question

[How do I restore the MySQL root user's privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658246/how-do-i-restore-the-mysql-root-users-privileges)

I think I can't do any thing except remove mariadb completely with all configure files.

**------------------update------------------**

I have no problem with my password, the problem is my root user has no privelages.

*please **don't** send solutions about changing password*

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following lines in your terminal.

1. Stop the MySQL Server.

   `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`
2. Start the mysqld configuration.

   `sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &`
3. Login to MySQL as root.

   `mysql -u root mysql`
4. Replace YOURNEWPASSWORD with your new password!

   `UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;`